# libgdx 0.9.8 compilation to html5 not working on phones browser

Tags: android, html, gwt, libgdx

I am building the libgdx demo app with Gdx setup GUI, then I compile it to html5 and deploy the war. 
Everything works fine in a desktop browser, but when I test it in a mobile browser, android 4.1.2 and 4.2 both chrome and default browser, I see a blank screen. Although the canvas element is render it's not showing the sprite.

No error is shown in the console of the web inspector.
WebGL is enabled in the default browser of android 4.1.2, I tested in http://get.webgl.org/.
I tried with current libgdx version which is 0.9.8 and nightly builds.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, version 0.9.8, it looks that is not supported for all mobile browsers.

For more info check http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=8879